# JavaScript object not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

The code below works on all browsers I have tried but does not work on IE. The `jsonObj` at ends up with all nulls. (Browsers tested Mac safari, chrome, firefox, PC FireFox, Opera, chrome) IE is the only one to fail. Can some one see my problem?

IE version 10

```
function Save() {
    var path = document.location.pathname;

    var Checked = "{";
    jsonObj = [];

    $('.questionsOnPage').each(function () {

        item = {}
        var id = this.id;

        jQuery(this).children(".questionCheckBox").each(function () {
            item ["id"] = this.id;
            item ["selected"] = this.checked;
        });

        jQuery(this).children(".question").each(function () {
            item ["question"] = this.innerHTML;
        });

        answers = {}

        jQuery(this).children(".answer").each(function () {
            answer = {};
            answer ["selector"] = $(this).attr("data-selector");
            answer ["answerText"] = $(this).attr("data-answerText");
            answer ["correct"] = $(this).attr("data-correct");
            answers [$(this).attr("data-selector")] = answer;
        });

        item["answers"] =  answers;

        jsonObj.push(item);
    });
```

Comment: What version of IE? It makes a lot of difference. Also, you're processing a lot of DOM, care to include it? (E.g. in FF/Chrome, Inspect element -> Copy outer HTML -> paste here/on pastebin)

Comment: Maybe adding **var** before item={} may help you

Comment: FYI, this has **nothing** to do with JSON. You are creating an array of objects, not JSON. There *might* be a problem with `item` being global. Make it local.

Comment: adding var worked, thanks!!!

Comment: Please declare all local variables as local variables.  Way too many implicit globals here.  You are asking for problems.

Comment: @TwilightSun should put that as an answer below and OP lascoff needs to accept and upvote it.

Comment: function not closed properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Deryck suggested I'll put this in the answer.

The solution to your problem: add **Var** before item={}

Different browser vendors have different implementation on the JavaScript engine. To my observation, when you push something into an array in IE, you're pushing a reference of the object instead of a cloned copy (not sure if this is true). So modifying item after pushing, would result in changing the previous pushed object. Adding var will assure that you'll get a new copy in each iteration step.

Comment: You just saved me an hour of frustration. Thank you!